# magento 1.8 multi language storeview with custom theme set up

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I am new to Magento. I am working on Magento 1.8 and having problem while creating multi-store-views for different language's. I have done some configuration from backend, I gpt the multiple-store-view. Its converted from English to French but its not converting to Malaysia language. my steps are as follows

**Note:**  I am using responsive custom theme.

1. Go to the site: http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations and download the proper language that you are looking for.
2. Extract and upload the files you downloaded to your Magento’s root directory. Keep in mind it will upload files to your app folder in Magento, but unless you try with a language that you already have there, it won’t overwrite anything as it’s a new language.
3. Once you finish uploading, go to your Magento’s Admin.
4. Go to: System>Manage Stores.
5. Click on “Create A Store View”.
6. Once there comes the really important thing: Put the name you want for the “Name” field, but in your “Code” field, make sure you enter your main theme followed by a “_” (underscore) and then the name of the language you want to use. Even if you used a new template that you did or purchase it would be under a main template type (default or base). Let’s say you have a new template you purchased called “MAG0873″ and its folder resides under “default”. Also, let’s say you installed Spanish language, then you would put “default_spanish” in this field.
7. Save it and now go to:  System>Configuration.
8. There, select your new Store View name from the “Current Configuration Scope” item in the top left column.
9. Now, go to the option: General>Locale.
10. After that, uncheck the option “Use Website” and make sure you change “Locale” field to the language you downloaded (be specific according to the dropdown list!).
11. Save it after changing it and now clean your cache and refresh your FrontEnd.

Now, few important things:
If you didn’t deactivate the original Store View a new dropdown will appear in the FrontEnd to change the language and the new Store View’s Name will appear there. Once you select it, the entire template should switch its language.
It might happen it switches language but, it also shows old/default template, well, no worries, this means you need to set up your new Store View to use the proper template according to your design set up. The next steps are specific for the persons who install templates through the System>Design option as I do (which I think is the easier and faster way).

1. Go to System>Design
2. Add a new Design.
3. In the “Store” field, select the new Store View you recently created.
   .Now select the “Custom Design” you previously installed in your system.
   Save it.

Now, your store should be using the proper design in the proper Store View (language).
Ok, now it happens that the hoe page doesn’t show exactly as you had it on the original (English) language? Well, it might be happening that the Home page is set up for an specific Store View. To fix it, just go to CMS>Pages, now click on the “Home” record (assuming you are using default settings that come with Magento) and then in its options make sure you have “Store View”  field set up to “All Store Views”. Save it now.

What's mistake i have done here.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to have a well configured multi-language Magento setup you need to follow the steps below:

- Setup a separate Store View for each language (System -> Manage
  Stores -> Create store view);
- Apply a Locale for each Store View (System -> Configuration ->
  General -> Locale Options, select Desired Store View in "Current
  Configuration Scope" drop-down in left-side navigation);
- Make sure that you have translated all of your CMS pages to all of
  your languages. You need to create a unique CMS page for each store
  view;
- If you'd like to use a separate theme for each language just do it in
  System–>Configuration–>General under the Design tab;
- In case you need to make a different set of categories in Navigation
  menu for each store view, you may control it by "Include in Navigation
  Menu" category attribute (Just choose a category for edit and go to
  General Information tab). Change all text attributes in Catalog Products and Categories for
  each store view

The more detailed guide find here:

http://sherodesigns.com/magento-tutorial/magento-tutorial-creating-multi-language-stores/